# What countries can I transit on my way to Kenya without requiring a visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, international-travel, kenyan-citizens

I am a usa resident with a Kenya passport what countries can I transit on my way to Kenya without requiring a visa for the country I transit through?

Comment: Saudi Arabia, there is a direct flight from JED to NBO, and there are direct flights from USA (JFK, IAD, LAX) to JED. You can transit in saudi without a visa.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need to leave the arrival/transit lounge of the airport (i.e. your luggage is checked through to your final destination, no sightseeing or change of airport), you can in any case transit in:

- Saudi Arabia (mentioned by MeNoTalk in the comments)
- One Schengen country including Belgium, France, Germany, the Netherlands or Switzerland. See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) for all the details.
- United Kingdom, if your US residence document [meets the requirements](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/kenya/transit/no)
- United Arab Emirates, including Abu Dhabi (at least [if staying less than 4 hours](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/transit-information/less-than-4-hours.aspx)) and Dubai
- [Turkey](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa)
- Ethiopia (because Kenyan citizens [don't need a visa there in the first place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Ethiopia))
- Hong Kong